# How to get html code in php when its done edited

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I create a WYSWYG (What You See is What You Get) editor, but I stuck when user is done editing the file, how can it be save.

I already tried `ob_start()` in PHP but it didn't capture the new changes.

```
<?php
    // Start the buffering //
    ob_start();
?>

// Html pages goes here. WYSIWYG editor made in js but should be save 
when user done edit it. 
// but when user press submit it only gets the default html code

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Get the content that is in the buffer and put it in your file //
    echo "<script>alert('Page is saved')</script>";
    file_put_contents('index1.html', ob_get_contents());
}   
?>
```

So, how can I save the new edited html and css code in php?

Already googled alot, but I didn't find anything reliable.

Any suggestions for what should i do to save the new edited html css and js code.

Thanks.

Comment: The submited content is in $_POST array.

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel, try using an existing editor like [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/).

Comment: yeah i know there is already WYSIWYG editors but i am in try to make one as i love to learn things...

Comment: same way all other editors work...update the form control with editor value when submit event occurs. Receive in $_POST